# There should be a "Silence", "Shut up", or "Ferme!" badge

Tags: feature-request, badges

Anything that gets 5 or more downvotes after counting any accidental up votes before getting closed and all within a short time period should be a badge. Unless its not that rare of course... Im hoping it is rare :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we want to reward "bad" behavior with a badge! Now the opposite might be worthwhile - a "0 to 60" badge for a question or answer that garners a number of upvotes very quickly.

Comment: There is the tumbleweed badge which is kinda similar IMO

Comment: LOL I've earned that badge - it's kind of the opposite.. no upvotes and no activity at all!

Comment: And, since it requires few views, tricky to do on most of the major sites.